SharePoint content and term stores unique per site based on master
I have a problem to solve that I am stuck in analysis/choice paralysis for.
Requirement:
A "master" content type with around 60 and growing variations of the master that are site/customer specific.  There are about 10 terms with subterms, each of these 10 have a column and are encapsulated in a top-level term group/set (I always mess up the terminology here but it can be either as the solution needs)
A content type is a list item (for use with a form) that is used for customer requests. Each customer has a unique subset of possible terms (of the 10 or so subsets) that are maintained by these managed terms and are given a column each in the content type.
I have a 'master' list that the staff use to capture what each customer list should render, and suspect using a flow I can trigger an Azure automation or ALM event to create/maintain the customer list and associated 'available terms' - then an intention to use a standardized SPFx form customizer using pnpjs/spfx predefined elements to render the form; the <DynamicForm> element.
However, I am yet to bridge the gap with a solution that is resilient
In essence, I'm trying to:

determine the best way to manage site based variants of a list content type using a 'master list'
have a generic SPFx form that can be served from a hub site that uses the logged in users identity to pull the right list column configuration for that customer to avoid having to maintain multiple form customizers
have the customer forms columns maintained by the master list - this could be either using hiding of terms in the column, having a flow/automation/alm only define the column with the unique set of terms for each column, or simply hiding of terms at form render time.

The closest I have gotten was maintaining a site term store for each site but this was unfeasible for the staff that would have to maintain them due to lack of technical prowess.
